# Gnuplot: plotting histograms on Y-axis

Tags: matplotlib, plot, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a histogram for the following data:

```
<text>,<percentage> 
--------------------
"Statement A",50%
"Statement B",20%
"Statement C",30%
```

I used the `set datafile separator ","` to obtain the corresponding columns. The plot should have percentage on the X-axis and the statements on the Y-axis (full character string). So each histogram is horizontal.

How can I do this in gnuplot?
Or is there other tools for plotting good vector images?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gnuplot `histogram` and `boxes` plotting styles are for vertical boxes. To get horizontal boxes, you can use `boxxyerrorbars`.

For the strings as y-labels, I use `yticlabels` and place the boxes at the y-values 0, 1 and 2 (according to the row in the data file, which is accessed with `$0`).

I let gnuplot treat the second column as numerical value, which strips the `%` off. It is added later in the formatting of the xtics:

```
set datafile separator ','
set format x '%g%%'
set style fill solid
plot 'data.txt' using ($2*0.5):0:($2*0.5):(0.4):yticlabels(1) with boxxyerrorbars t ''
```

The result with version 4.6.4 is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Christoph for the help. One more thing, how can I also print the percentage on the right of each box. Say something like 37% on the side of its corresponding box.

Answer (score 0):

@**Christoph** Thank you. Your answer helped me.

@**Slayer** Regarding your question to add labels using *gnuplot v5.2 patchlevel 6* and using @**Christoph**'s provided sample.

**Sample Code:**

```
# set the data file delimiter
set datafile separator ','

# set the x-axiz labels to show percentage
set format x '%g%%'

# set the x-axis min and max range
set xrange [ 0 : 100]

# set the style of the bars
set style fill solid

# set the textbox style with a blue line colour
set style textbox opaque border lc "blue"

# plot the data graph and place the labels on the bars
plot 'plotv.txt' using ($2*0.5):0:($2*0.5):(0.3):yticlabels(1) with boxxyerrorbars t '', \
     ''          using 2:0:2 with labels center boxed notitle column
```

**Sample Data Provided:(plotv.txt)**

```
<text>,<percentage> 
--------------------
"Statement A",50%
"Statement B",20%
"Statement C",30%
```

**Reference(s):**

1. [gnuplot 5.2 demo sample - textbox](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/textbox.html) and the related [sample data](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/gnuplot-main/ci/master/tree/demo/table.dat?force=True)

[gnuplot](/questions/tagged/gnuplot)